# After adding the -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution parameter, the idea console prints the content to force a newline

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I tried adding the jvm parameter to print some content, but when I add the -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution parameter, the console output is forced to wrap. If this parameter is not added, it is not forced to wrap. I suspect this is a bug. Please help me analyze the problem.
idea version :Build #IU-213.7172.25, built on March 16, 2022

```
public class MaxTenuringThreshold_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        byte[] byte1 = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        byte[] byte2 = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];

        YGC(40);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        YGC(40);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        YGC(40);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        YGC(40);

       
        Thread.sleep(3000);


       (TargetSurvivorRatio)=3M(Desired survivor size)
        byte[] byte4 = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        byte[] byte5 = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        byte[] byte6 = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];

       
        YGC(40);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        
        YGC(40);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        System.out.print("GC end!");
    }

   
    private static void YGC(int edenSize){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < edenSize ; i ++) {
            byte[] byte1m = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024];
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot after adding -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution parameter]

[image: Screenshot of console output]

Comment: What console you are speaking about? And where do you add the VM option? To IDE's VM options, or into the run configuration of your application? Couldn't reproduce that: https://i.imgur.com/Yc0QD3T.png

Comment: Open the Run/Debug Configurations configuration item and add this parameter to reproduce the problem.